# PageSpeed Insigths and GoDaddy Windows Hosting

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, server, hosting

I'm having an issue with cache in my webpage.
My webpage is hosted by GoDaddy, with the Economic Windows Server with Plesk.

[conexaomktdigital.com.br](http://conexaomktdigital.com.br)

It's a very simple site, I DONT USE PHP on it, only HTML, CSS and simple bootstrap JS.

When I run PageSpeed Insights, the results are telling me to optimize browser cache, including adding expire dates to my .css and images.
Mobile: 60/100
Desktop: 75/100

HOW I DO IT? I seek everywhere and don't see anything, everybody talks about .htaccess, but it's not apache, it's windows with plesk by GoDaddy... What should I do, can someone help me?

Comment: you should take a look at [this](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html)

Comment: gogaz that link is from 2003

Comment: already saw that link, too old, some tags doesn't not even have support anymore, but thanks anyway... still looking.
P.S: I tried using a file 'Web.Config', but it caused Error 500... so, or this file was wrong or it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and use a correct 'Web.Config' file. put it in your root folder.
You can find some information about how to use a web.config file with te right tags here: 
https://www.giftofspeed.com/leverage-browser-caching/

I use a very simple configuration, it appears to work nice for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".html" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
        <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
        <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
      </profiles>
    </caching>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

this will keep the files listed there in cache until it have some change.
No Error 500 for me, I think it will not happen to you too.